# Why are (R) Shiny factor levels changing when published using tidycmprsk::cuminc()

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a `tidycmprsk::cuminc()` function in R shiny that looks fine when I run it on my console but the factors get messed up when it's published. In ggsurvplot, this way works fine but in ggcuminc it does not.

I want to keep the High, Standard, and Low curves dotted and red, yellow, green respectively. And when Selected is picked, I want to add it to the end of the "H,S,L" curves and make it navy blue. If Negative is picked, I want to add it to the end of everything and make it light blue.

The code to create the factor levels:

```
# find the risk levels
risk_levels <- unique(combined_data$Risk)
    
# order the initial curves
desired_order <- c("High", "Standard", "Low")

# if picked, add selected to the end of the levels
if ("Selected" %in% risk_levels) {
   desired_order <- c(desired_order, "Selected")
}
if ("Negative" %in% risk_levels) {
   desired_order <- c(desired_order, "Negative")
}

# factor the Risk column based on the above
combined_data$Risk <- factor(combined_data$Risk, levels = desired_order)

sample_vector <- character(0)
legend_vector1 <- character(0) # turns into the legend title which will not show H,S,L.

# initialize palette and linetype vectors
palette_vector <- c("#BF355D", "#FAB66A", "#83BFA1")
linetype_vector <- c("dotted", "dotted", "dotted")
legend_vector <- c("High", "Standard", "Low")
        
# if Selected has data, add it to the end palette and linetype vectors
if (sample_size_selected > 0) {
   palette_vector <- c(palette_vector, "#041c3c")
   linetype_vector <- c(linetype_vector, "solid")
   legend_vector <- c(legend_vector, "Selected")
   legend_vector1 <- c(legend_vector1, "Selected")
   sample_vector <- c(sample_vector, sample_size_selected)
}

# if Negative has data, add it to the end palette and linetype vectors
if (sample_size_inv > 0) {
   palette_vector <- c(palette_vector, "#82b4f7")
   linetype_vector <- c(linetype_vector, "solid")
   legend_vector <- c(legend_vector, "Negative")
   legend_vector1 <- c(legend_vector1, "Negative")
   sample_vector <- c(sample_vector, sample_size_inv)
}
```

The code for the actual cuminc plot:

```
# the cuminc plot
rrfit <- tidycmprsk::cuminc(Surv(Years, EventID) ~ Risk, data = combined_data) %>%

        # makes it gg
        ggcuminc(outcome = 'Relapse',
                 theme = theme_minimal(),
                 size = 1,
                 linetype_aes = TRUE) +

        # changing the axis labels
        labs(
          x = "Years",
          y = "Cumulative Incidence"
        ) +

        # changing the axis scales
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1)) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,10),
                           breaks=seq(from=0,
                                      to=10,
                                      by=1)) +

        # changing the line color and type based on the palette and linetype vectors
        scale_color_manual(values = palette_vector) +
        scale_linetype_manual(values = linetype_vector) +
        
        # using the legend to show sample size
        add_legend_title(title = paste(legend_vector1, "n:", sample_vector, collapse = "\n"))

# adjusting the font size
rrfit <- ggpar(rrfit,
               font.x = 12,
               font.y = 12,
               font.caption = 12,
               font.legend = 12,
               font.tickslab = 12)
```

Here is a sample dput for the combined_data:

| Risk | EFS.eventID | Years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| High | Relapse | 3.1 |
| Standard | Relapse | 0.1 |
| Low | Relapse | 0.1 |
| Low | Censored | 6.3 |
| High | Relapse | 0.2 |
| Standard | Censored | 3.9 |
| Standard | Censored | 3.3 |
| Selected | Relapse | 0.9 |
| Selected | Censored | 3.1 |
| Negative | Relapse | 0.4 |
| Negative | Censored | 2.1 |